# How to destroy all the labels of the same kind in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button that creates a label when the user enters something that's not a number, the user can keep clicking the button and will create many of the same label but i am only able to destroy one label. I tried to fix it by adding a variable `v`, it will add 1 to v every time it displays the label, then it will tell the program to destroy `self.wrongval` until v = 0. But somehow the `for v in range(v)` only destroys one of the labels BUT when i try to print v, it comes out as 0. What can i do to destroy all of the same labels? Any help or suggestions on fixing this? thanks.

```
    def correct(self):
        global v
        global p
        try:
            if int(self.user_choice.get()) == answer:
                cor = Label(self.frame,text="Correct!")
                cor.grid(row=5, pady=20)
                p += 1
                self.sub.destroy()
                for v in range(v):
                    self.wrongval.destroy()
                    v -= 1
                nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", command=self.necs)
                nex.grid(row=4)

        except ValueError:
            self.wrongval = Label(self.frame, text="Please enter a number")
            v += 1
            print (v)
            self.wrongval.grid(row=5)
```

Comment: Why create new `Label`s when you could just hide or show a single one?

Comment: @quamrana How do you only show a single label and hide all the others?

Comment: Perhaps look into the [forget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method) method?

Comment: Why don't you just create the `self.wrongval` label outside `correct()` function, then update its text based on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(widget, tk.Label):
        widget.destroy()
```

with winfo_children() you get all the widgets inside of your frame.
Then you do filter them by a specific thing they have in common.
(*)Or you could do a seperate frame just for these Labels, it would be easier to get them. I dont know if it fit to your structur.

But maybe you think about just configure the text of the Label instead of creating a bunch of them.